# It seems the GET is not returning any thing although as per firebug the GET request is being fire with the blank response

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script>
    function country_state(sid) {
        var id = sid;
        console.log("Function called " + sid + "  " + $("#state").val());
        $.get("country.php?id=" + id, function(d) {
            console.log("Function returned " + d);
            alert("Returned: " + d);
            $(".media").html(d);
        });

    }
</script>
```

In this code the 1st error log is coming but not the 2nd.It seems the GET is not returning any thing although as per firebug the GET request is being fire with the blank response.please help.

Comment: Please post the GET request & response from firebug.

Comment: Is the response code of the request 200 or something else? That function will not be called if an error happens in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the error callback, look at the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
  // and remember the jqxhr object for this request
  var jqxhr = $.get("example.php", function() {
    alert("success");
  })
  .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
  .error(function() { alert("error"); })
  .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

  // perform other work here ...

  // Set another completion function for the request above
  jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve your code like this for example:

```
function send(id) {
            $.get('country.php', { id:id }, function(data) {
            var secureData = eval('(' + data.split('while(1);')[1] + ')');
            if (typeof callback == 'function') callback(secureData);
            alert(data);
        });
}
```

Why I use all that? check this and you will get the answer:
http://insecureweb.com/javascript/secure-your-ajax-request-with-jquery/
(it's a kind of security)

**Now, make sure in your PHP file you are expecting ID and not SID as your jQuery function:**

```
<?php
//$_GET['id'] the name of 'id' was defined on jquery $.get { param:param }
//this is a common mistake (getting confused of what you passed in parameters like for example using ID and SID)
  if ($_GET && isset($_GET['id'])){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    //do your work here

  }  
?>
```

Hope this helps and maybe clarify you something to do it in the right way because sometimes when you don't pass that if statement in php, you will receive a blank page (also empty response) and you can check it opening 'country.php' directly in browser.

Regards.